# Pause Android app until button press

Tags: java, android, android-studio, do-while, buttonclick

I have two methods: go() and stop(), and a for loop looping through these methods 3 times. go() activates automatically when the loop starts and stop() will only activate once a button is pressed 3 times:

```
private static int buttonPress;

for (int i = 0; i < 3, i++) {
    go();
    do {} while(pressCount < 4);
    stop();
}
```

Whenever the button the pressed, pressCount is incremented by 1:

```
public void button(View v) {
    pressCount++;
}
```

The problem is that with this setup, when the do while loop launches, the app freezes and crashes.

Is there any way to fix this while still having the go() activate before stop(), having stop() activate after pressCount is greater than 3, and looping through 3 times?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pause main thread, the app freezes.

```
private int loopCount = 0;
private int pressCount = 0;

public void button(View v) { /* Runs when button is clicked */
    if (loopCount < 4){
        pressCount++;

        if (pressCount == 3){
            pressCount = 0;
            loopCount++;
            stop();
        }
    }
}
```

This code runs `stop()` when the button is pressed three times, but runs that only three times. (After 9 presses nothing happens)

Answer (score 3):

you cannot block the main thread for more than 5 seconds if that happens then an anr (Application not responding) dialog pops up.

Comment: so is there any why to "pause" the app without blocking the main thread?

Comment: Use an alarm, or a timer or any number of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private boolean isStop = true;
private int buttonPressedCount = 0;

private void goOrStop() {
    if(isStop) {
      go();
      isStop = false;
    } else {
       stopIfCan(); // :)
    }
}

private void stopIfCan() {
    if(buttonPressedCount >= 3 ) {
        buttonPressedCount = 0; 
        isStop = false;
        stop();
    }
}

public void button(View v) {
    buttonPressedCount++;
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is that stop() HAS TO execute after the three buttonPress, with the if statement, the program will just skip over stop() instead of waiting if buttonPress is less than 3